# Pyspark- get unique URLs count for two days

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with pyspark for the first time and I want to get unique URLs count for consecutively two days. Suppose, one URLs comes in the system today and if that also comes tomorrow, I do NOT want to count that in tomorrow's unique counts. Columns are Date and Url_path

input
[image]

expected output
[image]
I tried this

```
display(
    df.groupBy( F.window(df['date'], "2 day"))
      .agg(F.countDistinct(F.col('host_path')).alias("unique_urls"), 
           F.count(F.col('host_path')).alias("total_urls"))
)
```

but it's giving me unique counts for that window. I want to get Net New counts for every single day.

Comment: Could you provide your sample input and expected output?

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. I just added example

Comment: A bit pseudo, but if you group the urls, you can check to count if date === lead(date, 1).over(Window.partitionBy(date).orderBy(date.asc))

Comment: @Khushboo Your requirement seems covered by group by as described above, but if you need a general N consecutive days number look for "Gaps and Island" problem, or I can provide an answer based on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result like this,

1. Prepping the dataframe

```
data = [('1/1/2023', 'abc.com'), ('1/1/2023', 'abc.com'), ('1/1/2023', 'xyz.com'), ('1/2/2023', 'abc.com'), ('1/2/2023', 'jkl.com'), ('1/3/2023', 'abc.com'), ('1/4/2023', 'abc.com'), ('1/4/2023', 'jkl.com'), ('1/4/2023', 'mno.com'), ('1/4/2023', 'mno.com')]

schema = ['date', 'host_path']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+---------+
|    date|host_path|
+--------+---------+
|1/1/2023|  abc.com|
|1/1/2023|  abc.com|
|1/1/2023|  xyz.com|
|1/2/2023|  abc.com|
|1/2/2023|  jkl.com|
|1/3/2023|  abc.com|
|1/4/2023|  abc.com|
|1/4/2023|  jkl.com|
|1/4/2023|  mno.com|
|1/4/2023|  mno.com|
+--------+---------+
```

2. Use [collect_set()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set.html) to collect all the urls for that day without any duplicates.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('date').orderBy('date')

df = df.withColumn("all_urls", F.collect_set("host_path").over(w))

df = df.dropDuplicates(['date', 'all_urls'])

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+--------+---------+---------------------------+
|date    |host_path|all_urls                   |
+--------+---------+---------------------------+
|1/1/2023|abc.com  |[xyz.com, abc.com]         |
|1/2/2023|abc.com  |[jkl.com, abc.com]         |
|1/3/2023|abc.com  |[abc.com]                  |
|1/4/2023|abc.com  |[jkl.com, mno.com, abc.com]|
+--------+---------+---------------------------+
```

3. Use [lag()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html?highlight=lag#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) to get the URLs that came one day prior

```
w1 = Window.orderBy('date')

df = df.withColumn("lag_urls", F.lag("all_urls", 1).over(w1))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+--------+---------+---------------------------+------------------+
|date    |host_path|all_urls                   |lag_urls          |
+--------+---------+---------------------------+------------------+
|1/1/2023|abc.com  |[xyz.com, abc.com]         |null              |
|1/2/2023|abc.com  |[jkl.com, abc.com]         |[xyz.com, abc.com]|
|1/3/2023|abc.com  |[abc.com]                  |[jkl.com, abc.com]|
|1/4/2023|abc.com  |[jkl.com, mno.com, abc.com]|[abc.com]         |
+--------+---------+---------------------------+------------------+
```

4. Get the difference between `all_urls` and `lag_urls` using [array_except](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_except.html?highlight=array_except#pyspark.sql.functions.array_except)

```
df = df.withColumn('difference', F.array_except('all_urls', 'lag_urls'))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+--------+---------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+
|date    |host_path|all_urls                   |lag_urls          |difference        |
+--------+---------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+
|1/1/2023|abc.com  |[xyz.com, abc.com]         |null              |null              |
|1/2/2023|abc.com  |[jkl.com, abc.com]         |[xyz.com, abc.com]|[jkl.com]         |
|1/3/2023|abc.com  |[abc.com]                  |[jkl.com, abc.com]|[]                |
|1/4/2023|abc.com  |[jkl.com, mno.com, abc.com]|[abc.com]         |[jkl.com, mno.com]|
+--------+---------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

5. Get the size/length of the arrays in the `difference` column and if null then get the size/length from `all_urls`

```
df.withColumn("unique_urls", F.when(F.size(F.col("difference")) < 0, F.size(F.col("all_urls"))).otherwise(F.size(F.col("difference")))).select("date", "unique_urls").show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----------+
|date    |unique_urls|
+--------+-----------+
|1/1/2023|2          |
|1/2/2023|1          |
|1/3/2023|0          |
|1/4/2023|2          |
+--------+-----------+
```

6. So, everything together looks like this,

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('date').orderBy('date')

w1 = Window.orderBy('date')

df = df.withColumn("all_urls", F.collect_set("host_path").over(w)) \
        .dropDuplicates(['date', 'all_urls']) \
        .withColumn("lag_urls", F.lag("all_urls", 1).over(w1)) \
        .withColumn('difference', F.array_except('all_urls', 'lag_urls')) \
        .withColumn("unique_urls", F.when(F.size(F.col("difference")) < 0, F.size(F.col("all_urls"))).otherwise(F.size(F.col("difference")))) \
        .select("date", "unique_urls")

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----------+
|date    |unique_urls|
+--------+-----------+
|1/1/2023|2          |
|1/2/2023|1          |
|1/3/2023|0          |
|1/4/2023|2          |
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tushar for commenting the solution. I really appreciate it. Do have anything in mind to make it more efficient. I am working with millions for row containing thousands of distinct count each day. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a flag that identify whether the same `host_path` appears within yesterday or today. Then count based on the flag.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('host_path').orderBy('date')
cond = F.col('uniq_flag').isNull() | (F.col('uniq_flag') == True)

# If the last time of the same host_path is more than 1 day, uniq_flag is True (it is unique)
df = (df.withColumn('uniq_flag', F.datediff(F.col('date'), F.lag('date').over(w)) > 1)
      # I will only need to count when it is unique or first time
      # (uniq_flag = None when first time)
      .groupby('date')
      .agg(F.count(F.when(cond, F.col('host_path'))).alias('unique_urls')))
```